# how to remove suffix from dateitem and selectitem

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

Hi I need help regarding removing suffixes from items in dynamic form. I used:

```
final DynamicForm Form = new DynamicForm();
Form.setWidth("*");
Form.setHeight(22);
Form.setNumCols(10);
Form.setDataSource(wds);
Form.setTitleOrientation(TitleOrientation.LEFT);
Form.setTitleSuffix("");
```

I used `setTitleSuffix()` to remove the `(:)` it worked a bit but not totally some fields suffix have gone. but some are still there. I want remove `(:)` from the items and also some items have focus. That also i need to remove with regards subodh.

Comment: Which items' titles are still suffixed with ':'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For form fields which are set as required use

`form.setRequiredTitleSuffix("");`

For the second question some fields are on focus some are not in focus .  if you have given

`TextItem.setRequired(true);`

the field gets focus.the fields which have not been given

`TextItem.setRequired(true);`

will not be in focus.